# Does const and let create a context object in the scope chain?

Tags: javascript

I know that const and let have block scope in contrast to var. But say I have the following code:

```
{
  let a = 0;
}
```

Does it actually create a scope object in the scope chain just like when a function is executed or let and const are still place in either global or function context object?

Comment: Do you mind rephrasing your question? What is a scope object, or scope chain? What do you mean by object?

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#With_let_and_const

Comment: `{ let a = 0 }` is this a correct syntax for a object

Comment: @Abhishek-Saini it's not an object literal, it's a block statement with a variable declaration inside.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use a block (even if it's a plain block not attached to anything), when the interpreter runs across the `{` that delimits the block, a new Lexical Environment (which is a map of variable names to the values they contain in the current scope and its descendant scopes) is created. See [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-lexical-environments):

> A Lexical Environment consists of an Environment Record and a possibly null reference to an outer Lexical Environment. Usually a Lexical Environment is associated with some specific syntactic structure of ECMAScript code such as a FunctionDeclaration, a BlockStatement, or a Catch clause of a TryStatement and **a new Lexical Environment is created each time such code is evaluated.**

It's not that the `let` inside the block creates a new environment, it's the existence of the block itself that creates a new environment.

The code being executed may be on the top level, in which case the (global) environment will bind the variable name to its value (eg, the identifier `a` to the value `0`). Or, the code being executed may be inside a function, in which case the same sort of thing is true (except that references to an `a` with that value of 0 will only be visible from code inside the function, due to standard lexical scoping rules).

Comment: (Of course I'd expect any engine to optimise away the creation of the lexical environment if no local variables are declared in it)